# jsPDF - Cannot render html to pdf

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf, jspdf

I need to render a view to pdf but from a jquery `get()`. It returns a view and I try to insert this returned data in doc `jsPDF()` but it doesn't work!

The view have the all, metadata, css links, js links and the content.

My jquery function:

```
function exportToPdf()
{
  $('#exportToPdf').on('click', function(e)
  {
    var ref = $(this).attr('data-ref');

    $.get("/to-pdf/"+encodeURIComponent(ref), function(data)
    {
      var doc = new jsPDF();
      doc.text(data, 10, 10);
      doc.save('a4.pdf');
    });
  });
}
```

How can I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
function onClick() {
  var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
  pdf.canvas.height = 80 * 11;
  pdf.canvas.width = 80 * 8.5;    
  pdf.fromHTML(document.body); //Your HTML content goes here
  pdf.save('test.pdf');
};
```

Comment: Hi, it returns the pdf empty! @BajinderBudhwar

Comment: replace the document.body with html content and I assume you are also including jsPDF library.. This should work.